# Cannot add tag "conditional-probability"

Tags: support, tagging

I have just asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810960/are-the-notations-pxdx-and-pdx-equivalent) and wanted to add tag "conditional-probability"(x 841), but the tag doesn't appear without any notification. Is there any restrictions on using some tags?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[conditional-probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional-probability) is a synonym of [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability), so if you add that tag to a question, it is automatically converted to [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability). The tags were not merged when the synonym was created, therefore there are still questions having the tag [conditional-probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional-probability).

Comment: Thank you! Can I read somewhere which tags are synonyms?

Comment: Yes, you can. There's a [tag synonyms](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) page (linked at the bottom of the [tags page](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags)). But let me warn you, that page is ugly. Also, it's hard to interpret.

Comment: There is now a separate discussion whether or not there *should* be this tag synonym: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27653/tag-management-2018/28753#28753