# Unable to add "span" tag to (linear algebra) question

Tags: support, tagging, tag-management

I thought that "span" would be a good tag to add to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3353529/find-a-subset-of-s-1-0-i-i-2-3-2-i-1i-i-that-forms-a-bas) on Mathematics Stack Exchange, but when I click on "Edit Tags", type "span", click on "span", and click on "Save Tag Edits", I don't see the "span" tag appearing, the way an additional tag usually has when I have added other tags to other posts.  I found that I could add other tags to that post, and I had this problem when trying to add the "span" tag to other posts, so there seems to be a problem with the "span" tag in general rather than with the post I wish to edit.  (I thought it could relate to the fact that "span" has few letters, but I had no trouble with tag "pde", which has fewer.)

P.S.  I don't frequent math.meta.stackexchange.com much; is this question appropriate for this forum, or for meta.stackexchange.com?  I'm sorry if this is the wrong forum.

Sincerely,

J. W. Tanner

Comment: This is the case since span a synonyms of linear algebra. Every time the tag span is added to a post, it is automatically changed to linear algebra. 

You can check it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/linear-algebra/synonyms). More tag synonyms suggestions can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

Comment: I didn't know that, @ArcticChar, but that explains it; thank you; if you post your comment as an answer, I would be happy to accept it

Comment: Here is [link to the discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/19354#19354) that eventually lead to creating this particular synonym.

Comment: Some older posts which seem related: [Cannot add tag “conditional-probability”](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23377) and [Why does the tag “(solution-verification)” show as “(proof-verification)”?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27197)

Comment: Meta is exactly the place for this type of questions. No problem there. The same principle that holds in main works here: the same question may have been asked/discussed earlier, so we encourage users to search. Granted, the repetition rate in meta is not nearly as bad in meta as it is in main. Some do recur often enough to attract instant votes to close (rants about closing a specific questions spring to mind), but this theme is not that frequent. We do have annual tag management threads as places designed to work out the kinks of the tagging system.